# "Save Image" is not an option for the ActivityViewController. I can only "Save to File" (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiactivityviewcontroller, swiftui-navigationview

I am creating a meme object which consists of a UImage and two TextFields.
I am recreating a Storyboard application with **SwiftUI**, so I have used the UIViewControllerRepresentable.

Once the completionHandler "is completed" I should be able to save the new image, however the only option that comes up is "Save to Files" which results in only being able to save as a PNG.

My ViewController code is as follows:

```
struct ShareViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    //the data you need to share....
    @Binding var topText: String
    @Binding var bottomText: String
    @Binding var imagePicked: UIImage?
    @Binding var memedImage: UIImage?

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIActivityViewController {
        //define an instance of ActivityViewController
        let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [memedImage], applicationActivities: nil)
        //completion handler
        controller.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?, completed: Bool, returnedItems: [Any]?, error: Error?) in
            //create a meme if completed
            if completed {
                print("HERE")
                print(memedImage)
                self.saveMeme(topText: self.topText, bottomText: self.bottomText, originalImage: self.imagePicked!, memedImage: self.memedImage!)
               
                
            }else{
                print("error")
            }
            
        }
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIActivityViewController, context: Context) {}
    
    func saveMeme(topText: String, bottomText: String, originalImage: UIImage, memedImage: UIImage) {
        
        let meme = Meme(topText: topText, bottomText: bottomText, original: originalImage, memed: memedImage)
        
    }
    
}

//This is the View where I call the controller via .sheet: 

struct MemeSwiftUIView: View {
    
    @State private var topText: String = ""
    @State private var bottomText: String = ""
    @State private var imagePicked: UIImage?
    @State private var memedImage: UIImage?
    @State private var isShowingPicker = false
    @State private var isReadyToShare = false
    @State private var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .camera
    @State private var shareButtonEnabled = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            features
            //top bar
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        Button(action: {
//creates a UIGraphicsImageRenderer to create final memedImage
                            generateMemedImage()
                            isReadyToShare = true
                            
                        }){
                            Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                        }
                        .disabled(!shareButtonEnabled)
                        .sheet(isPresented: $isReadyToShare, content: {
//sends the data to ShareViewController:
                            ShareViewController(topText: $topText, bottomText: $bottomText, imagePicked: $imagePicked, memedImage: $memedImage)
                        })
                    }
                    
                }
//...rest of struct View
```

I have already added the necessary info.plist requirements regarding the camera/picture saving features and I have seen that I have a UImage present that is being saved (printed to console):
Optional(<UIImage:0x600000bbc630 anonymous {1668, 2500} renderingMode=automatic(original)>
Why else would the **"save image"** option not be available?